# Local Sitecore site SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE error unless Fiddler is running

Tags: fiddler, sitecore9.3

I have not encountered this before. I cannot see my local sitecore website unless I keep Fiddler running... Is there a way to decouple and uninstall Fiddler now?

I tried removing the DONOTTRUSTFIDDLER root certificate, tried using the tool in Fiddler to 'remove interception certs', but it just keeps giving that SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE error unless I reinstall Fiddler and trust the certs.. otherwise I cannot get work done and Fiddler just uses resources in the background for no reason.

How can I get rid of it like it never happened?

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore 9.3 had a bug where the Identity Server certificate would throw SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE error in Firefox​.​ The error was caused by wrong certificate usage flag set by the Sitecore Installation Framework (should be Digital Signature instead of Data Encipherment). This was fixed in a later version of SIF.

As version and error logs are not shared the above is the most likely explanation. Alternatively you might be experiencing a very similar browser/certificate issue.